# Удаление из БД после выдачи результата

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, sql

Есть база из 10.000 строк, каждая из них это новое задание для сотрудника. Нужно удалять строку из БД, после того, как сотрудник перейдет на страницу и нажмет на кнопку «выдать новую строку». Данные новой строки выведутся, но из БД удаляться, чтобы при выполнении нового задания или выполнении одновременно с другим сотрудником, не выдавались одни и те же строки.

**Вопрос**: как это можно реализовать? И как сделать моментальное удаление, чтобы при одновременной выдачи новой строки в разных сессиях браузера, данные не успели пересечься. Возможно стоит сделать выдачу рандомной. Подскажите как бы сдедали вы?

Comment: Добавьте поле ключа о прочтении. Вы давайте данные с ключом,  к примеру,  no-read.  А при открытии меняйте на read

Comment: @Николай отличная идея. А как мне при выдаче результата сразу изменить поле на read?

Comment: После скрипта вывода отправьте запрос об изменении поля в данной строке базы.

Comment: Можно прямо после запроса в базу select следующей строкой отправить запрос update